# Correct placement of functions in PHP code

Tags: php

I am fond of writing neat code by doing things the right way. Here is my question, When writing PHP code(procedural) does where you place your function call matter with respect to function definition.

For example:

```
if( isset( $_POST['submit_form'] ) )
{
 //Here is function definition 
 test_input($data)
  {
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data)
     .......
 }
 //Here I am making function calls
  $name = test_input( $_POST['username'] );
  $emailid = test_input( $_POST['useremail'] );
```

**and**

```
 if( isset( $_POST['submit_form'] ) )
{

 //Here I am making function calls
  $name = test_input( $_POST['username'] );
  $emailid = test_input( $_POST['useremail'] );

  //Here is function definition
 test_input($data)
  {
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data)
     .......
 }
```

Comment: The difference is that the latter won't work… *In this particular case.*

Comment: `validate_data` is bad, very bad, anyway.

Comment: @deceze Would you mind telling me why?

Comment: @Martin Allow me to introduce you to Hoisting. But, as deceze mentions, *in this particular case* there is no hoisting.

Comment: @Martin are you sure?

Comment: Oh didn't know thank you for your contributions. So will I be good enough using trim () only instead of the function validate_data?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I take that back, I believed this to be so but a quick test proved me incorrect

Comment: What exactly are you validating…?

Comment: @deceze I am validating form data, `username` and `email`, Server-side validation

Comment: You're not "validating" it, you're *modifying* it. Validation == "does this match my expectations?" `trim`, `stripslashes` == "turn this into something else…"

Comment: @deceze Yah you are right maybe my function name was  deceiving.I have edited my question and changed `validate_data()` to `test_input()` since I am not validating data